# Meteor packages folder location

Tags: meteor

In Meteor documentation I've read that I can test my custom Meteor package locally under one of my Meteor projects by placing the custom package under the /packages folder and entering (meteor add), yet I can't locate the Package folder...I've looked under .meteor folder but can't find any packages folder, the only packages folder I found was under .meteor/local/build/programs/packages so is this the folder where I should place my custom package to test? if now where I can find the packages folder? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because this folder does not exist by default in a Meteor project (just like the `client/` or `server/` folders).

You need to create this directory at the root of your project, place your custom packages under this directory and `meteor add` them.

Comment: there is a packages file and because of that, i'm not able to create the new packages directory. What do i do!?